# What's the relationship between UI animation and the main runloop

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, animation

i have this code to wait for a loading task, showing a activityIndicator view

```
  if (isLoading) {
    self.tipView = [[BBTipsView alloc] initWithMessage:@"loading..." showLoading:YES parentView:self.view autoClose:NO];
    self.tipView.needsMask = YES;
    [self.tipView show];
    while (isLoading) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
    [self.tipView close];
}
```

the loading view will animate until the isLoading become false.here is my problem:
running a runloop in main thread will block the main thread until there is a source event comes or timer fire. but why the loading view keep animating while the main runloop didn't return?

-----edit by bupo----

I found that when timer fire the runloop won't return. This will make sense that the animation refresh ui by CADisplayLink timer fire.

```
Note that from the perspective of NSRunloop, NSTimer objects are not "input"—they are a special type, and one of the things that means is that they do not cause the run loop to return when they fire.
```

Comment: Modern animations have little to do with the RunLoop.  They rely timer primitives called Display Links, which can be run on background threads to ensure a good refresh rate linked to the display, rather than the CPU.

Comment: you mean the UI refresh not run on the main thread?

Comment: The display callback that you get is main-thread only.  The timer is what runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSRunLoop` method `runMode:beforeDate:` runs until the given date OR until it finds a single event to deal with - after which the call returns. You're calling it on the main run loop (`[NSRunLook currentRunLoop]`). Hence, even though you think you're blocking the main run loop, you're not - you're causing events to be serviced. Hence, the animation timer can function, even though you might think you're 'blocking' the main run loop.

To confirm this, comment out the call to `runMode:beforeDate:` and you should see that the UI freezes until the operation completes.

**Edit:** see CodaFi's comment on your question. What actually happens if you comment out the call to `runMode:beforeDate:`, out of interest?

**Original answer:**

This style of code isn't recommended for starting and stopping UI animations. **Don't mess around with run loops unless you have to.** And having a tight loop that checks for boolean flag changing from elsewhere is often a code smell that means there's a better way.

Instead, do it asynchronously and without sitting on the main thread:

```
   // on main thread
   self.tipView = [[BBTipsView alloc] initWithMessage:@"loading..." showLoading:YES parentView:self.view autoClose:NO];
   self.tipView.needsMask = YES;
   [self.tipView show];
} // end of the method

- (void)loadingHasFinished {
    // assuming this method called on main thread
    [self.tipView close];
}
```

Obviously you'll have to ensure the `loadingHasFinished` is called as appropriate.

If `loadingHasFinished` is called on a background thread rather than the main thread, you'll want something like this:

```
- (void)loadingHasFinished {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tipView close];
    }); 
};
```

Comment: yes, i know there is a better way. but in this case i just want to know if ui animation refresh ui through the main runloop?